# php - losing session variables while creating custom headers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

i am using Vue with Jquery as a frontend and php as backend. Because i my client app runs on different computer in LAN than server to simulate real world circumstances i get:

> Failed to load http://192.168.0.15/game/src/server/Action.php: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.15:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

So i created custom header to prevent it:

```
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

However if i do that i am loosing any

> $_SESSION

data. Is there a way to prevent it? I use $.ajax from jQuery to post data to server and while setting inside one call a session data i can not retrieve it in second call although in the end of first call while checking $_SESSION['user_id'] i get all variables set correctly.
Any ideas ?

Comment: both sites are in my LAN, i control them fully

Comment: If you can't use cookies to maintain the session, which you can't if these are not on the same domain, assume that's the case since using CORS... Pass session identifier, use something like HMAC, OAUTH2, etc.